# How to parse an array to json using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to parse a hash to json but in the index.json.jbuilder I get empty hash.

**what am I doing wrong:**

```
  def self.fake_objects 

    fake_objects = {id: 1,
                  title: 'appointment one',
                  description: 'bla bla bla',
                  start_time: '2014-08-19 14:00:00.000000000 Z',
                  end_time: '2014-08-19 14:30:00.000000000 Z'}  
  end
```

events_controller

```
  def index
    @events = Event.all
    @fake_objects = Event.fake_objects 
  end
```

index.json.jbuilder

```
(@fake_objects).to_json do |event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :description
  json.start event.start_time
  json.end event.end_time
  json.url event_url(event, format: :html)
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fake_objects 
    fake_objects = Event.new(id: 1,
                  title: 'appointment one',
                  description: 'bla bla bla',
                  start_time: '2014-08-19 14:00:00.000000000 Z',
                  end_time: '2014-08-19 14:30:00.000000000 Z')
  end 
end
```

Comment: `@fake_objects` is likely nil in your view. You don't set it in the controller.

Comment: @evanx You have defined `fake_objects` but you are using `@fake_objects` check once

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just omitted the controller part, I edited the post.

Comment: does not to_json apply to ActiveRecord::Base objects ?

Answer (score -1):

try something like:

```
json.events @fake_objects do |json, event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :description
  json.start event.start_time
  json.end event.end_time
  json.url event_url(event, format: :html)
end
```

but `@fake_objects` should be defined as `[]`, for single event you could write:

```
json.event do |json|
  json.extract! @fake_object, :id, :title, :description
  json.start @fake_object.start_time
  json.end @fake_object.end_time
  json.url event_url(@fake_object, format: :html)
end
```

If you need just array of results (without `events: []`) write `json.array! ..`

Comment: I when I use json array like json.array!(@fake_objects) I get: undefined method `id' for [:id, 1]:Array

Comment: it looks like your `@fake_objects` is not `Array`, but `Hash`

Comment: If you want render single `Hash` item you could use second variant (even without `json.event ..`) but instead of `@fake_object.id` wirte `@fake_object[:id]`